# Terminator installed via Homebrew "Incompatible library version"

Tags: osx, python, gtk

I've installed Terminator from the `homebrew/gui` tap, but when I ran it, it raised this error:

```
You need to install the python bindings for gobject, gtk and pango to run Terminator.
```

I edited `/usr/local/bin/terminator` (it's just Python) to display the error message, and I got this:

```
dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glib/_glib.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glib/_glib.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _glib.so requires version 4401.0.0 or later, but libgobject-2.0.0.dylib provides version 3401.0.0
```

The fact that this is showing up does not surprise me, as I've had a similar error with pretty much every Python program that uses GTK.

Let me know if I should ask on Ask Different instead.

Comment: Have you raised this on the tap's issue tracker?  It sounds like a packaging bug to me.

Comment: It's not an issue with the tap, I get this error with all Python programs using GTK.

Comment: Then it's probably an issue with one of the common dependencies, which is still homebrew-packaged.